# Testlink1.9.7 and redmine2.6.0 integration issue

Tags: redmine, testlink

i looked up a lot of information, and the issue tracker file written as ordered，while the intergration still failed，I don't know what's wrong。

here is the configuration information.

issue tracker code：

```
<issuetracker>
<apikey>5e538dc08d383359e8a411ce14e18bf9900d9a98</apikey>

<uribase>https://localhost:3000/</uribase>
<uriview>https://localhost:3000/issues/</uriview>

<projectidentifier>xyz_iphone</projectidentifier>
<tracker_id>xyz_iphone</tracker_id>

</issuetracker>
```

redmine project info：
name：xyz_iphone identifier：xyz_iphone

testlink project info：
name：xyz_iphone identifier：xyz_iphone version id：xyz_iphone

Comment: What do you mean integration failed? Can't connect at all? Or maybe you can't create new issues?

Answer (score 2):

From your configuration, I can tell some of the fixes.

1. *tracker_id* should be *trackerid*
2. *trackerid* is the id of your Tracker not the name of your Tracker. You can find the tracker id by going to *Administrator > Trackers* and hover on the tracker you want to use. It should be 1, 2 ...

However, this integration just helps you to post/view issues to/from Redmine. If you want to display Testlink test case in related issue in Redmine, you have to use plugin in Redmine as well.
http://www.r-labs.org/projects/rp-testlinklink/wiki/TestLinkLinkEn

Hope this help.